# Navigational Bar - Making Transition Cover Full Height

Tags: css, navbar

So basically, I need this transition to cover the full height of the navbar, and the width to be smaller and more contained, here's my CSS:

```
ul {
  background-color: #282828;
  border-bottom: 7px #276095 solid;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width:100%;
height:50px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
position:fixed;
z-index:10;
  margin-top: 0px;

}
li {
  display:inline;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-left: 30px;
font-size: 24px;
padding-top:0px;
  margin-top:0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
        width: 100px; height: 100px;
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #282828 50%, #276095 50%);
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-position 1s;
    transition: background-position 1s;
}
li:hover {
      background-position: 0 -100%;
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
```

And here's my html:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<ul>
  <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="forum">Forums</a></li>
  <li><a href="shop">Shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="members">Members</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you were to see this code, you would notice that when you hover over a menu item, it has a slidedown transition, but I cannot seem to figure out how to have it slide from the top to the bottom. You will also notice that the width is kind of weird, I want it to be smaller and even.

Comment: If you want to see the code live: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBBboW

Answer (score 0):

Adding `padding-top: 15px` and `padding-bottom: 17px` to the li will make the animation span the full height.

`padding-left` and `padding-right` control the width. You have one as 30px and the other as 50px, which is why it is uneven. If you want to space the li's apart more but still have the blue animated part be thinner, you can add in margin-left or margin-right to increase the spacing.

Comment: Thanks! But it still doesn't start at the top, it does go to the bottom now though.

Comment: I noticed you had `padding: 0` in your li already. Is that still there? Maybe it is overriding the new line for you. These steps are working for me in Chrome + Firefox.